# Trying to remove repeated sets of characters towards the end of a string in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file,
and at this point *%ext%* would be something like *.mp3 *.mp4 *. *. *. *.
Number of times *. is repeated towards the end is unknown (in this case it's repeated 4 times)
So I did something like this to remove all the *. repeated towards the end, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
:extman
echo %ext%
:: setting %extz% as last three %ext% characters
set extz=%ext:~-3%
if "%extz%"==" *." set ext=%ext:~0,-3% & goto extman
if '%errorlevel%'=='1' goto NEXT
:NEXT
echo %ext%
pause > nul
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
The desired output for %ext% is

```
*.mp3 *.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The space before `&` goes into `ext`.

Solution 1: remove the space: `set ext=%ext:~0,-3%& goto extman`
Solution 2: quote the assignment: `set "ext=%ext:~0,-3%" & goto extman`

BTW it's possible to shorten the code:

```
:extman
    if "%ext:~-3%"==" *." set "ext=%ext:~0,-3%" & goto extman
```